# Call jQuery trigger with jQuery object

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, bind, jquery-events

I have a jQuery object which I'd like to pass to jQuery.trigger. The bound function should receive this object and do something with it. However, it seems like the bound function receives a DOM node instead of the full jQuery object which was passed to trigger.

Example:

```
var doSomething = function(event, object) {
    object.myPluginFunction(); 
}

$("#selector").bind("finished", doSomething);

var myObject = $("#table").myPlugin();
$("#selector").trigger("finished", myObject);
```

The problem is: in `doSomething` I cannot access `object.myPluginFunction`... The received object appears in fact not to be an object. Instead, it is a DOM node. It seems to me like jQuery strips it.

Is there a way to get access, without calling `$.myPlugin` or introducing callback?

I use jQuery 1.4.1, and cannot upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the trigger parameters in an array

```
$("#selector").trigger("finished", [myObject]);​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbNWd/)

Also, note that since this "finished" is custom event that you created, and therefore not associated with any UI (native) event, it is more correct to invoke using [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) instead of `trigger`.

Answer (score 0):

Another exemple:

```
var obj = (function() {
    var that = {};
    var name = "toto";

    that.getName = function() {
        return name;    
    };

    return that;
})();

$("#btnTest").bind("customEvent", function(evt, obj) {
    console.log(obj.t1.getName());
});

$("#btnTest").click(function() {
    $("#btnTest").trigger("customEvent", {t1: obj});
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EJLwu/3/